# SELECT date('now') does not work in Python + SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

In [the SQLite documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), it says you can get the current date by running the query

```
SELECT date('now');
```

and indeed it works in the SQLite command line:

```
sqlite> SELECT date('now');
2012-03-03
```

However, when I try to use it in a Python program, the same query doesn't work:

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('results.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT date(now);')
```

says `no such column: now`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing quotes around `now`.

Try `c.execute("SELECT date('now');")`

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing some ticks?
Do c.execute('SELECT date(\'now\');') works?

Comment: This works, and so does the answer above provided by @grifaton.

Answer (score 0):

The 'now' literal can be omitted. If the date() function
has no parameters, the 'now' string is assumed. So
the script can be written as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect(':memory:')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()     
    cur.execute("SELECT date()")
    today = cur.fetchone()[0]

    print today


$ ./today.py
2013-02-05
```